# I have problem in getting image path, when I get image in on activity result data is not empty but unable to get its path

Tags: android, kotlin

This is what I am trying to do. But the loged path is not correct. When I try to get file from loged path it says file not existed.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data?.data != null) {
                val imagePath: String? = data.data?.path
                if (imagePath != null) {
                    Log.d("logKey", imagePath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is no path as you have seen. And no need for a 'path' as you should use the uri `data?.data` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Add this class in your project

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.DocumentsContract
import android.provider.MediaStore

//import android.provider.<span id="IL_AD11" class="IL_AD">MediaStore</span>;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
object ImageFilePath {
    /**
     * Method for return file path of Gallery image
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return path of the selected image file from gallery
     */
    var nopath = "Select Video Only"
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {

        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        val isKitKat = true

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"
                            + split[1])
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    java.lang.Long.valueOf(id)
                )
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                if ("image" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("video" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("audio" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                }
                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                return getDataColumn(
                    context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs
                )
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {

            // Return the remote address
            return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(
                context,
                uri,
                null,
                null
            )
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }
        return nopath
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is <span id="IL_AD2" class="IL_AD">useful</span> for MediaStore Uris, and other file-based
     * ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context
     * The context.
     * @param uri
     * The Uri to query.
     * @param selection
     * (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs
     * (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    fun getDataColumn(
        context: Context, uri: Uri?,
        selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    ): String {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                uri!!, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null
            )
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(index)
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return nopath
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     * The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri
            .authority
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     * The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri
            .authority
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     * The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri
            .authority
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     * The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri
            .authority
    }
}
```

Add this code in your onActivityResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.data != null) {
            val uri = data.data
           val  realPath = ImageFilePath.getPath(this, data.data!!)
            //                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());
            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: file path : $realPath")
            try {
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)
                // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
                binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                binding.imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```